# Using innodb_buffer_pool and query cache

Tags: mysql, innodb, query-cache

I'm trying to optimize a MYsql[innodb] database and i want to know if its a good idea to activate both innodb_buffer_pool and query cache and what are the principle factors I must take in consideration while optimizing my db.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of *available* RAM.  Turn off the Query cache.

Comment: The QC is of very little use, especially in production systems.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory#query_cache).  In particular, the QC was not designed to be very big.

Comment: 70% of available RAM  
is that mean available RAM after allocated to other resource or complete RAM size on the system/VPS. If I have 4gb 2core VPS then innodb_buffer_pool_size should be ~1.4 gb is that right?

Comment: Start with that.  Keep an eye on total memory usage.  (eg, via `top`)